# Where to find author/creator of tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, badges

In an attempt to get the badge [Taxonomist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), I created the [affine-transformation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affine-transformation) tag, however, I have not been able to confirm that I am the author of this tag.

Where can I see the author of a specific tag and, moreover, where can I visualize my Badge Progress to get the [Taxonomist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge?

Comment: I think you've missed the spirit/point of that badge though it seems you've accomplished it with a different tag. The idea is that you created a tag so useful that *other* people have used it on 50 different questions. Not that you yourself went and edited 50 questions to apply it. In fact I distinctly recall a cautionary tale here on GISMeta (which of course I can't find... @whuber?) where someone did just that and had all the edits reversed, badge revoked, and might have been suspended/banned for specifically abusing the system in such a way.

Comment: I didn't mean to do so. The affine-transformation badge was not randomly chosen. I have an R package for applying affine transformations and the topic is interesting for me. So I noticed most of related questions were tagged as [tag:transformation] and wanted to disambiguate such tag, so that affine related questions could be easily identified. Besides that, I couldn't find a reference for "[...] that *other* people have used it on 50 different questions." I found "Create a tag that is applied to 50 questions" in SE meta.

Comment: It's discussed in many places, like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/ I'm referring to your other [tag:geometry-conversion] efforts though. I didn't examine affine, but it was obvious with that one and reeks of gaming the system. All of your edits had to be approved, and were, and the tag may even have merit. But 50 edits is excessive for a tag - at that point we're talking 'mass retag' and a lot of question bumping, and should be done with mod tools. I'm not 100% clear if this is a violation or not, and may pose that question myself, because if it *isn't* I have a few of my own.

Comment: Fair enough. However, if something is to be reversed is the badge, not the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been asked over on Meta SE as [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created) and it has [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) where, among others, [Jeff Atwood answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6822/215590):

> It is unlikely we will do this (that is, show who created a tag) due
>   to the Taxonomist badge gaming concerns outlined above.. and over and
>   over and over in about fifty other posts on meta.
>
> I can't see anything good come of making this information public.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure that it was not possible. So, if someone gets it, the Taxonomist badge will come totally "by surprise."