# Do we need [projection-mathematics] and [reprojection-mathematics] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At [Using/synonymizing/merging [coordinate-system] and [projection] tags?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/using-synonymizing-merging-coordinate-system-and-projection-tags) we synonymized a number of tags related to coordinate systems.

Today I noticed [Re-projection issues with Azimuthal Equidistant](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341044/re-projection-issues-with-azimuthal-equidistant) with tags for [projection-mathematics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection-mathematics) and [reprojection-mathematics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reprojection-mathematics).

Are both or either of these tags necessary, or could one or both be synonymized with another tag?

Answer (score 4):

Following the line of the synonymization between [projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection) and [coordinate-system](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system), I would agree to synonymize [projection-mathematics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection-mathematics) and [reprojection-mathematics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reprojection-mathematics) to [coordinate-system](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system) as well.

Mainly because I think they should be synonymous with [projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection).

The terms are not synonymous. However, I don't think synonymous tags should necessarily refer to synonymous terms.

What I would find useful is to add in the definition of [cordinate-system](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cordinate-system) that the tag:

> also applies to projective geometry and coordinate system transformations.

I think that it would be resolved that when a user writes *projection* in the field of tags, he/she note that everything related to projections and reprojections is labeled as [coordinate-system](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system), which after all is very useful to group in that way all the questions that refer to the coordinate systems in which geographic information is analyzed and represented.

---

It occurs to me that the description or definition of what a coordinate system is, is not enough to describe the tag:

> A reference framework consisting of a set of points, lines, and/or surfaces, and a set of rules, used to define the positions of points in space in either two or three dimensions.

And that adding a phrase referring to cartographic projections and coordinate system transformations could help describe the tag and its synonyms.

It may be convenient to open a new question about this idea. For now it is raised here and in the chat.

---

A wiki edit was submited for approval, wich includes the phrase:

> This tag also refers to cartographic projections and coordinate system transformations.

Comment: These have now been made into synonyms with a view to merging them later.

Comment: While I very much agree that projection-mathematics and reprojection-mathematics are synonyms, I very much disagree with making them synonyms of 'coordinate-system'.  Someone with a genuine interest in reprojection mathematics could previously very easily identify 96 questions.  Now they have to wade through 5,869 questions.  What benefit does this bring?

Comment: @JimT Among those 96 questions at least two are the same, which generated this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341044/re-projection-issues-with-azimuthal-equidistant .Which showed an inconsistent use of those tags (. Someone with a genuine but exclusive interest in the mathematics behind a reprojection would not be interested in that question). The benefit that synonymization brings is to avoid the inconsistent use of tagging.

Comment: Misuse of a tag in an anecdotal incident is no argument against generalizing so much that nothing can be found for a particular subject - and in this case I already agree the two mathematics tags should be synonyms.  I have an interest in re-projection mathematics, and I imagine others do too.  How do I now narrow a search down from 5,869 questions?

Comment: @JimT a comment won’t make your case but an answer might. A synonym is easily backed out if the community supports your proposal but when a synonym proceeds to be merged that tag is totally removed from the questions that had it.

Comment: @PolyGeo Maybe I don't understand the merge process, I can't search for questions with the [projection-mathematics] tag right now (is the synonym already merged?) but I can see that tag in some questions of the following search: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=mathematics%20projection%20is%3aquestion

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca This is worth reviewing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work A synonym treats the original tag (which still exists on questions) as if it were the master synonym whereas a merge removes the original tag from all questions.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca We merged a lot of our synonyms a bit over a year ago via https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/can-we-merge-all-of-our-current-tag-synonyms

Answer (score 2):

Agree completely with making tags projection-mathematics and reprojection-mathematics synonyms with a view to eventual merging.  The two terms are identical.

While I further agree the subject of these two tags is indeed a sub-class of the wider 'Coordinate-System' tag, I disagree with any further synonymization.

There is a significant quantity (>5,500) of questions with coordinate system tagged.  Following synonymization, anyone with a genuine interest in reprojection-mathematics (~100 questions) would really struggle to filter that list down if so desired.

There is a danger here of generalising tags so much that less popular (but not less important) subject areas are eclipsed.

*TL;DR:
Merge the two tags.  No further action required.*